# Selecting the output when iterating through two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, append, output

So when I loop through two of my **arrays(associative)** in js and append the output in my table, I get 3 `undefined`. The output looks like this:
 [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLGfc.png)

You can see in the console that the iteration happens consecutively,
which is why I get the undefined values given the nature of the array

This is the jQuery call to my controller where I get both my arrays:

```
function getArtworks() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: './index.php/Controller/getArtworks',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (jsonData) {
      showArtsInTable(jsonData);
      console.log(jsonData);
    },
    error: function () {
      alert('Error :' + jsonData);
    }
  });
}
```

This is where I loop through my arrays and append to my table:

```
function showArtsInTable(jsonData) {
  let table = $('#tblArt');
  $('#artForm').hide();
  table.empty();
  table.append('<thead>');
  table.append('<tr>');
  table.append('<th>Namn</th>');
  table.append('</tr>');
  table.append('</thead>');
  $.each(jsonData, function() {
    $.each(this, function(i, value) {
      console.log(value);
      table.append('<tbody>');
      table.append('<tr>');
      table.append(
        "<td><a href='#' onclick=getArtworkByID('" +
          value['ID'] +
          "')>" +
          value['NAME'] +
          '</a></td>'
      );
      table.append('</tr>');
      table.append('</tbody>');
      table.append('<tr>');
      table.append('<td>' + value['MAX(BID)'] + '</td>');
      table.append('</tr>');
    });
  });
}
```

stringified console log:

```
[
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "NAME": "Chaviour",
      "CATID": ""
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "NAME": "simpleDrop",
      "CATID": ""
    },
    {
      "ID": "3",
      "NAME": "Chattash",
      "CATID": "Janne"
    },
],
[
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "DATE": "2019-03-16 19:39:06",
      "MAX(BID)": "7500"
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "DATE": "2019-03-16 19:39:06",
      "MAX(BID)": "5000"
    },
    {
      "ID": "3",
      "DATE": "2019-03-16 20:55:48",
      "MAX(BID)": "9000"
    }
]
```

I only want my table to append values under the columns "Name" and "Bid".
How can I go about that?

Comment: I hope i interpreted your comment correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i understand what your after.

Just to check, you want the following output?

Name | Bid

Chaviour | 7500

simpleDrop | 5000

Chattash | 9000

You need to first join up your data by ID:

```js
const data = [
     [
        {
          "ID": "1",
          "NAME": "Chaviour",
          "CATID": ""
        },
        {
          "ID": "2",
          "NAME": "simpleDrop",
          "CATID": ""
        },
        {
          "ID": "3",
          "NAME": "Chattash",
          "CATID": "Janne"
        },
    ],
    [
        {
          "ID": "1",
          "DATE": "2019-03-16 19:39:06",
          "MAX(BID)": "7500"
        },
        {
          "ID": "2",
          "DATE": "2019-03-16 19:39:06",
          "MAX(BID)": "5000"
        },
        {
          "ID": "3",
          "DATE": "2019-03-16 20:55:48",
          "MAX(BID)": "9000"
        }
    ]
]

const tidyData = data[0].map((a) => {
  // find the matching item by ID
  let match = data[1].find((b) => b.ID === a.ID) || {}
  // return the union
  return {
    ...a,
    ...match,
  }
})

console.log(tidyData);
```

This returns the following data, from here is should be pretty easy to show in a table:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "NAME": "Chaviour",
        "CATID": "",
        "DATE": "2019-03-16 19:39:06",
        "MAX(BID)": "7500"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "NAME": "simpleDrop",
        "CATID": "",
        "DATE": "2019-03-16 19:39:06",
        "MAX(BID)": "5000"
    },
    {
        "ID": "3",
        "NAME": "Chattash",
        "CATID": "Janne",
        "DATE": "2019-03-16 20:55:48",
        "MAX(BID)": "9000"
    }
]
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!